# jQuery, How to create a copy button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on this structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript">
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
    var myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";
    clip.setText(myTextToCopy);
    clip.glue('d_clip_button');
</script>
<div id="d_clip_button" style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>
```

but it doesn't work, need your help to figure this out. thanks in advance!

Comment: @anoop - simply it doesn't work.

Comment: open fire bug and check whether there is any console error.

Comment: From the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*. Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ZeroClipboard, copy button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404955/jquery-zeroclipboard-copy-button)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your jquery code in a `document.ready()` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
                var myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";
                clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
                clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
});
```

So as to wait for the DOM to be loaded so your `#d_clip_button` element is present when accessing it from jquery.

Comment: @Ray: Are you sure `ZeroClipboard.Client` actually exists? Which library are you using? If it is [this one](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) then it looks like it is initialized differently.

Comment: @Nelson the OP has asked a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404955/jquery-zeroclipboard-copy-button) now. Voted to close this question.